# Migrate Mail from one server to another

Tags: linux, email, migration

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to move a full mailbox from one server to another.
We're migrating a site from an Windows server to a linux server.
is there any way to export them from the windows environment and import them into the mailbox on linux?

I'm using Plesk 9 on the new server.

Thanks!
Troy

Comment: What software is running on both sides?

Comment: The answer would be *quite* different if the Windows side is running the built-in POP3/SMTP services or Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out [imapsync](http://freshmeat.net/projects/imapsync/).  We used it,in part, when we migrated users from GroupWise to Zimbra.  The tool is Zimbra's recommended method for mailbox migrations, but imapsync should work anywhere both sides are able to talk IMAP.